# Is every positive function defined from $\mathbb{N}$ with real values continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

I wonder if every positive function defined from $\mathbb{N}$ with real values is continuous.

I want to prove that a function in the measure space $(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the measure that counts the elements, defined on $\mathbb{N}$ is measurable.
So, if I had that every positive function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f^{-1}(<\alpha,+\infty>)\in P(\mathbb{N})$, so $f\in M^{+}(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}))$.

Comment: If you give $\Bbb N$ the discrete topology, every function $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: Why is continuity relevant to assess measurability?

Comment: I take it that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: yes, it is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$